# fft of perturbations on a circle in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, fft

I have an image showing a circle (shown) with a mix of different modes of perturbation imposed on it. It is inconvenient to "unwrap" this circle into Cartesian coordinates to perform FFT on account of some other additional features. Is it possible to use FFT on the circle - can I pass FFT an object or a binary matrix with 1s inside the shape, 0s outside to obtain the power spectrum on that surface?

[image]

Comment: I think this requires some extra preprocessing, not something FFT can handle directly. Please post your image and your attempt to extract the surface perturbations.

Comment: Can you post this image in question so we can visualize the question better?